# Probability of a triangle from stick broken into $n \geq 3$ pieces

Tags: probability

There is an interesting problem about the probability of getting a triangle when breaking a stick into three pieces ([MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r)).  It seems that when breaking a stick into *any* number of pieces $n \geq 3$, choosing any three of those pieces results in a triangle with the same probability of $\frac{1}{4}$.  Consequently, the expected number of triangles from a stick broken into $n$ pieces is
$$\frac{1}{4} {n \choose 3}$$

Can we prove that choosing any three pieces from a finite length stick broken into $n\geq 3$ pieces results in a triangle with the same probability of $\frac{1}{4}$?

Here is a Monte Carlo script for inspection: https://trinket.io/python3/1edf5c8ca1